# Approximating $e^{-x}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, approximation

So we all know that the Taylor series for $e^x$ is $1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6}+\ldots$ Similarly for $e^{-x}$ it comes comes out to be $1 - x + \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{6}+\ldots$ Now for the problem I have at hand $x \gg1$. I am confused as how does the series converge for a very large $x$ because according to the Taylor series you should get a very large negative value for large $x$.

Also, we know that when $x$ tends to infinity, $e^{-x}$ should tend to zero. Is there any way to approximate $e^{-x}$ for large but finite values?

Thanks for your help

Comment: For what purpose do you need the approximation?  What constraints are you working under?  Most programming languages have the exponential function built in.

Answer (score 3):

The Taylor series converges for all $x$.  If $x=50$, say, the terms will grow until the one $\frac {50^{50}}{50!}\approx 2.9 \cdot 10^{20}$  The next term is $-\frac {50}{51}$ of this and they continue decreasing.  They will cancel very delicately so the final result is $e^{-50}\approx 1.9\cdot 10^{-22}$

You are correct that the Taylor series is not a useful way to get the answer.  One way is to use [repeated squaring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to get the value for integral exponents.  Then if you wanted $\exp(-50.12345)$ you could use the Taylor series to get $\exp(0.12345)$  I would guess that computer libraries start with $2^x$ because they can handle the integer part of $x$ easily.  Once you have one exponential, you can use the properties of logarithms to get the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the help but I am not looking to resort to computational method. I understand what you are saying though.
Given this explanation I am guessing there is no way of approximating the e^-x with a very large x? Like the way you can approximate the Taylor series of e^x to 1 + x for a very small x.

Comment: If you know that $\log 10 \approx 2.30$, you can use that.  Then $\log_{10} e^{-x}=-x \log_{10} e \approx \frac {-x}{2.30}$  Now take the integer part to get you started.  For $e^{-50}$ we would get $\log_{10} e^{-50} \approx \frac {-50}{2.30} \approx -21.715$.  Now if you know that $\log_{10} 2 \approx 0.3$ you can see this is $2 \cdot 10^{-22}$ which is within $5\%$

Answer (score 1):

As Ross explains, this Taylor series converges for all $x$, but it's probably the case that your Taylor polynomial did not have enough terms to illustrate that yet.

As for approximating, $e^{-50}=(e^{-1})^{50}$. If you want to keep using Taylor series somehow, you can use it to approximate $e^{-1}$. Only using up to the tenth degree approximant, we have $e^{-1}\approx0.367879464\ldots$ and Taylor's Theorem proves that this approximation is within $\frac{1}{11!}$ of correct. Also it's an overestimate. In fact since the series is alternating, we can squeeze $e^{-1}$ between two adjacent approximants, like bere between the degree $10$th and degree $11$th.

$$0.367879464\ldots-\frac{1}{11!}<e^{-1}<0.367879464\ldots$$

Raising to the $50$th power

$$\left(0.367879464\ldots-\frac{1}{11!}\right)^{50}<e^{-50}<(0.367879464\ldots)^{50}$$

These outer expressions are relatively quickly computed by repeated squaring, writing $50=32+16+2$. You'd have to square five times because of the $32$.

$$1.92875\times10^{-22}<e^{-50}<1.92876\times10^{-22}$$